# Primefaces update the panel before f:setPropertyActionListener

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I have the following managed bean which has a `selectedElement` property and some components in a primefaces view binded to it inside an auto update `outputpanel`, i have a `commandButton` and `f:setPropertyActionListener` to set the `selectedElement` then update the panel, i get `Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:`
i think the update proess fires before setting the property , i have another view in different page do the same procedure without errors !
the managed bean code is:

```
package boddooo.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import boddooo.entity.Element;

@ManagedBean(name="ob")
@SessionScoped
public class objectsbuilder {

UserTransaction ut=null;

@PersistenceContext(unitName="game")
private EntityManager em;

Context icontext=null;
public objectsbuilder() throws NamingException{
    icontext=new InitialContext();
    ut=(UserTransaction)icontext.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
}

private List<Element> elements;

private Element selectedElement;

public Element getSelectedElement() {
    return selectedElement;
}

public void setSelectedElement(Element selectedElement) {
    this.selectedElement = selectedElement;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void loadElements(){
    Query q=em.createNamedQuery("Element.findAll");
    elements=(List<Element>)q.getResultList();
}

public List<Element> getElements(){
    return elements;
}

}
```

and the view is :

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" header="Elements">
        <p:dataGrid value="#{ob.elements}" var="element" style="padding:0px;text-align:center" columns="5">
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton value="" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;width:40px;height:40px;background-image: url('resources/images/objects/#{element.name}.png');background-size: 40px 40px;">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{element}" target="#{ob.selectedElement}"></f:setPropertyActionListener>
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataGrid>
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Name"></p:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText value="#{ob.selectedElement.name}"></p:inputText>
                <p:outputLabel value="Type"></p:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText value="#{ob.selectedElement.type}"></p:inputText>
                <p:outputLabel value="Class"></p:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText value="#{ob.selectedElement.class_}"></p:inputText>    
                <p:outputLabel value="Upgradable"></p:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText value="#{ob.selectedElement.upgradable}"></p:inputText>
                <p:outputLabel value="Duplicated"></p:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText value="#{ob.selectedElement.duplicated}"></p:inputText>
                <p:outputLabel value="Period"></p:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText value="#{ob.selectedElement.period}"></p:inputText>                                    
            </p:panelGrid>              
        </p:outputPanel>        
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

Comment: When exactly is the PNFE thrown? This wasn't explicitly stated in the question. Is it thrown when the output panel is shown, or when the form in the dialog is submitted? Nonetheless, a full stack trace would have removed/answered all ambiguity.

Comment: the problem was the selectedElement property has a null initial value when i  set it to the first Element it solved the problem.